# HTML/Javascript login page using CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I've been trying to login to write a script using CasperJS that logs in to my work's router login page, and I'm a little lost...

The html for the login page is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30314127/help.rtf

Thanks in advance,
Ronka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure anybody is going to write the code you need.  Casperjs has pretty good documentation.  You need to request the page, find the id's of the login and sendKeys.  I haven't run into any issues of not being able to log into a web based application using casper.  IF you're completely at a loss I have a video you can watch which enters data into an Ajax application, which shouldn't be too much different than what you're trying to do. 
[Filling out Ajax forms](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kefil5tCL9o)